# Firebase Realtime Database querying not working

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filter

I'm trying to retrieve some values instead of others. In fact, I want to search for users by their names.

I've tried using `queryStarting(atValue: input)`and `queryEnding(atValue: "u{f8ff}")` but I couldn't find the right solution.

```swift
let input = searchInput.text?.lowercased()
print("Search for \(input!)")
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Usernames").queryStarting(atValue: input).queryEnding(atValue: "u{f8ff}").queryOrderedByKey()

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let user = users.value as? [String:AnyObject]
            let id = user?["id"] as! String
            Users.init(userId: (id))
            print(users.key)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also added `queryOrderedByKey()`. If I don't add that part, it doesn't retrieve anything.
What I want is only retrieve the values starting by what I write in the textfield.

```
Usernames
----- charles
----------id: charles's uid
----- pierre
----------id: pierre's uid
----- bob
----------id: bob's uid
----- lu
----------id: lu's uid
```

The problem is that for example if the input is 'L' (to search for lu), it retrieves [lu]. Then if the input is 'Bo' (to search for bob), it retrieves [lu] and [bob], not only [bob] as I want. And obviously if the input is 'C' (to search for bob), it retrieves [lu], [bob], [pierre], and finally [charles].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query starts at your input which is correct, but ends at `u{f8ff}` - meaning if you start `bo`, you'll also get words starting with `c`, `d`, etc.

What you need to do is end at the the highest value that starts with you string, e.g. for an input of `bo` you would want to end at `bo\u{f8ff}`. You can do this by concatenating your input with that unicode value, i.e.:

```
...queryEnding(atValue: input + "\u{f8ff}")... // <-- Also note that the unicode character is escaped here
```